# Google Maps API Employee Tracking History

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, gps, polygon

I have build employee location history tracking app in Ionic 4.

The process is as follows:

**1- There is a service which fetches the current location after 5 second**

**2- Upload the fetched coordinates to database**

But sometimes the location fetched is incorrect i.e 4-5 meters away from where the current employee is. I dont know why is this happening even though I am using accurate location fetching.
Anyway,

In admin panel, I draw the polygon on Google map from the coordinates which were saved.
[image]

As you can see the polygon and the whole track is quite weird.

Is there any way to draw the lines as we get in directions API?

Or something like trailing line drawn like this in life360 App.
[image]

**I want the history locations to be drawn quite smoothly on maps instead of weird polygons line which doesnt bother the roads and paths**

Comment: [Roads API - Snap to Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Directions API. Input all the points as waypoints and the response will contain an encoded polyline that will be on actual roads and look nicer than a polyline.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: You are limited to 23 waypoints and billed at a higher rate above 10 waypoints.

Comment: Sure but that doesn't mean it isn't a viable solution to the question that was asked. 

Since he doesn't have turn-by-turn geolocation of the user, Driections API is  the only available method to create a polyline that reasonably approximates the route.

Comment: The purpose of the Snap to Roads from Roads API is exactly to... snap points on roads when you have points that are not very precisely placed on a road. So IMO it is much more suitable than to use the Directions API. Also the limits are 500 requests per second and 100 points per request.

Comment: Ok so offer that as an alternative answer. It doesn't mean using the Directions API isn't a viable option. Also the Directions API will give you a more natural path between points, and the Roads API will just snap to the nearest point.